# Collecting pay while on leave of absence?

Tags: united-states

Can you still get paid if you are on leave of absence from work?

I was told when I run out of sick time to go for leave of absence, what does that mean and can I still get paid?

Comment: Depends on company policy, and if you have long/short term disability insurance. We can't answer this, ask your employer's HR/payroll department.

Comment: "Leave of absence" is generally an unpaid leave. You may be eligible for insurance/disability payments though.

Answer (score 6):

In the United States, leaves of absence as covered in the [FMLA](http://www.dol.gov/whd/fmla/) are not required to be paid, and therefore are often unpaid - though many professional firms do pay for certain kinds of leaves of absence.

- Maternity leave: Commonly unpaid in the US, although some firms explicitly pay it and others explicitly consider it a kind of short-term disability and cover it under their STD policy.  Ask your employer.
- Short-term disability: Many firms pay for insurance for their employees, which offers short-term disability coverage at a percentage of their regular pay (for example, a firm I used to work for offered 60% by default, and you could buy up to 80%) after you have been out for several weeks, for the first few months; [Met Life](https://www.metlife.com/individual/employee-benefits/group-disability/group-short-term-disability.html) suggests six months to a year is their standard, for example.  You would commonly need to either use sick/paid leave or go unpaid for the first several weeks before it kicks in (a kind of deductible, basically).  This only applies if you are disabled (ie, sick or injured in some way that prevents you from working), although it does cover non-work related injuries.
- Long-term disability: Many firms also pay additional insurance for Long term disability, which also offers a percentage of your salary for the period after STD covers (so, six months to a year plus).  Again, you can read the [Met Life](https://www.metlife.com/individual/employee-benefits/group-disability/group-long-term-disability-insurance.html) page for a good example.  (Not trying to suggest this coverage - they just have good explanations.)  This is again offered by your employer, and often can be 'bought up' to a higher percentage.

FMLA leave of absences primarily mean you are required to be offered your job back after your leave is complete (up to twelve workweeks) or an equivalent job at a similar pay rate.  Check with your employer as to exactly what is relevant in your specific situation.